# Travis-ci stages - conditional logic

Tags: travis-ci

This is my travis.yml file followed by the latest run
https://travis-ci.com/github/harryyy27/allies-art-club:

```
sudo: required

services:
  - docker

stages:
  - name: before_deploy
    if: branch = master
  - name: before_install
    if: branch != master
  - name: scripts
    if: branch != master

before_install:
  - docker build -t harryyy27/allies_art_club/frontend -f ./client/Dockerfile.dev ./client
  - docker build -t harryyy27/allies_art_club/backend -f ./src/Dockerfile.dev ./src
scripts:
  - docker run -e CI=true harryyy27/allies_art_club/frontend npm test
  - docker run -e CI=true harryyy27/allies_art_club/backend npm test


before_deploy:
  - docker build -t harryyy27/aac-client ./client
  - docker tag harryyy27/aac-client registry.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP/client
  - docker build -t harryyy27/aac-src ./src
  - docker tag harryyy27/aac-src registry.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP/src
  - docker build -t harryyy27/aac-nginx ./nginx
  - docker tag harryyy27/aac-nginx registry.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP/nginx
# Log in to docker CLI
  - echo "$DOCKER_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$DOCKER_ID" --password-stdin
  - curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install.sh | sh
  - echo "$HEROKU_API" | docker login -u "$HEROKU_USERNAME" --password-stdin registry.heroku.com
deploy:
  skip_cleanup: true
  provider: script
  script:
    docker ps -a;
    docker push harryyy27/aac-client;
    docker push registry.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP/client;
    docker push harryyy27/aac-src;
    docker push registry.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP/src;
    docker push harryyy27/aac-nginx;
    docker push registry.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP/nginx;
    heroku container:release client src nginx --app $HEROKU_APP;
  on:
    branch: master
```

However, I'd like to know why my branch != master does not work for the before_install and scripts stages. It runs both of these stages even on master branch after merging my pull request.

(I am aware of the other issues with this travis.yml, I have raised them as separate questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this, set it up differently though. See below. I think the stages have to be set up with the jobs/include object as seen below

see new travis.yml

```
sudo: required
language: generic

services:
  - docker

stages:
  - dev
  - prod

jobs:
  include:
    - stage: dev
      if: NOT(branch=master)
      scripts:
        - docker build -t harryyy27/allies_art_club/frontend -f ./client/Dockerfile.dev ./client
        - docker build -t harryyy27/allies_art_club/backend -f ./src/Dockerfile.dev ./src
        - docker run -e CI=true harryyy27/allies_art_club/frontend npm test
        - docker run -e CI=true harryyy27/allies_art_club/backend npm test
    - stage: prod
      if: branch=master
      before_deploy:
        - docker build -t harryyy27/aac-client ./client
        - docker tag harryyy27/aac-client registry.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP/client
        - docker build -t harryyy27/aac-src ./src
        - docker tag harryyy27/aac-src registry.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP/src
        - docker build -t harryyy27/aac-nginx ./nginx
        - docker tag harryyy27/aac-nginx registry.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP/nginx
      # Log in to docker CLI
        - echo "$DOCKER_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$DOCKER_ID" --password-stdin
        - curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install.sh | sh
        - echo "$HEROKU_API" | docker login -u "$HEROKU_USERNAME" --password-stdin registry.heroku.com
      deploy:
        skip_cleanup: true
        provider: script
        script:
          docker ps -a;
          docker push harryyy27/aac-client;
          docker push registry.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP/client;
          docker push harryyy27/aac-src;
          docker push registry.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP/src;
          docker push harryyy27/aac-nginx;
          docker push registry.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP/nginx;
          heroku container:release client src nginx --app $HEROKU_APP;
```

***note I had to add language to avoid a Rakefile error. Best to use generic here as using node_js will prompt travis to look for a package.json and and a "make test" error will occur

---